# jQuery Carousel - HTML Markup changing with certain pictures

Tags: jquery, html, carousel

I'm using the following plugin on my website: http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/

It works fine however on certain images, the markup breaks. I tried fixing it but i can't fix it.

I think the problem is with the image - it's a picture of a giraffe and the giraffe has a big neck so is it possibly breaking out of the size of the div containing it.

Anyone had this problem before?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you  would probably post a snap of it, it would be good to check your problem.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh this is clearly Giraffeoverflow. It happens to me all the time on iOS.

Comment: Yeh for some reason the previous answer was deleted, this was a case of Giraffeoverflow.